# placing a link (a) aligned bottom with his container (li)

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have the following view : https://jsfiddle.net/jcrqhqLq/

I'd like to align the "Add to cart" buttons to the bottom of their container, so the buttons of every plans are all horizontally aligned, but I can't manage to do it. I tried to add `position: absolute; bottom 0;` on the buttons, but it breaks the container.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding this in your code

```
.pricing-table .plan{position:relative;}
    li.plan-feature:last-child {
        min-height: 65px;
    }
    li.plan-feature:last-child a {
        bottom: 10px;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        width: 95px;
    }
```

```css
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.pricing-table .plan {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #b0b2ab;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
.pricing-table .plan:hover {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px #b0b2ab;
}

.pricing-table .plan .plan-name {
    background-color: #5e5f59;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}
.pricing-table .plan:hover .plan-name {
    background: #4e9a06;
}

.pricing-table .plan .plan-name span {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.pricing-table .plan ul {
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.pricing-table .plan h2 {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.pricing-table .plan ul li.plan-feature {
    border-top: 1px solid #c5c8c0;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}
.pricing-table .plan ul li.plan-feature .plan-feature-description {
    margin: 0;
    color: #777;
    font-size: .9em;
}
.pricing-table .plan{position:relative;}
li.plan-feature:last-child {
    min-height: 65px;
}
li.plan-feature:last-child a {
    bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 95px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row row-eq-height pricing-table">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="plan">
                <div class="plan-name">
                    <h2>Plan #1</h2>
                    <span>24.90 €</span>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="plan-feature">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tincidunt, urna et hendrerit rutrum, dui eros efficitur massa, at mattis justo tortor eget nisl.</li>
                                            <li class="plan-feature">
                            Feature #1
                            <p class="plan-feature-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </li>
                                        <li class="plan-feature"><a href="/app_dev.php/cart/add/2" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="plan">
                <div class="plan-name">
                    <h2>Plan #2</h2>
                    <span>39.90 €</span>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="plan-feature">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tincidunt, urna et hendrerit rutrum, dui eros efficitur massa, at mattis justo tortor eget nisl.</li>
                                            <li class="plan-feature">
                            Feature #1
                            <p class="plan-feature-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </li>
                                            <li class="plan-feature">
                            Feature #2
                            <p class="plan-feature-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </li>
                                        <li class="plan-feature"><a href="/app_dev.php/cart/add/3" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the padding in your css code to put the buttons at the bottom:

```
.pricing-table .plan ul li.plan-feature {
    border-top: 1px solid #c5c8c0;
    padding: 15px 10px 0 10px;
}
```